# Enviar informacion a una ventana modal , con SpringBoot y thymeleaft

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

estoy desarrollando una app , y en una vista necesito hacer que al presionar un boton , se llame un evento del controlador y aparezca un detalle en una ventana emergente modal, el problema es que he probado del mil maneras distintas y la ventana modal siempre aparece vacia, sin la informaciòn que envio desde el controlador. Estos serian los controladores :

Controlador de la vista principal:

```
 @GetMapping("/lista-comandas")
    public String listaComandas(ModelMap modelo) {
        List<ResumenComanda> comandas = resComandaServicio.listarComandasSinFinalizar();
        modelo.put("comandas", comandas);
        
        Integer cantidad= comandas.size();
        modelo.put("cantidad", cantidad);
        
        
        Integer tpoTotal =resComandaServicio.sumaDemoraTotal();
        
        int horas= tpoTotal/60;
        int minutos= tpoTotal%60;
        
        modelo.put("horas", horas);
        modelo.put("min", minutos);
        
        return "lista-comandas";
    }
```

Controlador que envia la informacion a la ventana emergente :

```
   @GetMapping("/detalle/{id}")
    public String detalleComanda(@PathVariable String id,ModelMap modelo) {

        Integer nro = resComandaServicio.obtenerNroComanda(id);
        List<Comanda> detalle = comandaServicio.detalleXNro(nro);        
        modelo.put("detalle", detalle);

        return "lista-comandas";
        
    }
```

Esta seria la vista en html :

`

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet"   
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Lista de comandas</title>

</head>
<body >

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div th:replace="/fragments/navbar :: nav"></div>
        <br>
        <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5 ">

            <h1 class="display-4">Lista de Comandas</h1>

        </div>
        <hr class="mb-4"/>
        <div class="row justify-content-center ">

            <div class="col-6 mt-1">

          <div th:unless="${comandas.isEmpty()}" class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                    <p th:text="${cantidad + ' comandas. ' + horas + ' horas y ' + min}+' 
           minutos de demora total'" ></p>
                </div>  

                <div th:if="${comandas.isEmpty()}" class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                    <p>No hay comandas en espera </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6 mt-1">

                <div th:if="${exito}!=null" class="alert alert-success item-1" role="alert">
                    <p th:text="${exito}"></p>
                </div>     
                <div th:if="${error}!=null" class="alert alert-danger " role="alert">
                    <p th:text="${error}"></p>
                </div>  

            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row" style="height: 250px;">

            <div class="col-12 border shadow"  >
                <div class="table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar">
                    <table class="table text-capitalize">
                        <thead class="table-dark">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">id</th>
                                <th scope="col">Nro comanda</th>   
                                <th scope="col">Cliente</th>
                                <th scope="col">Demora en minutos</th>
                                <th scope="col">Precio Total</th>
                                <th scope="col">Acciones</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody th:each="comanda,iterator : ${comandas}" >
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row" th:text="${iterator.index+1}"></th>
                                <td th:text="${comanda.nroComanda}"></td>
                                <td th:text="|${comanda.cliente.nombre} 
                                 ${comanda.cliente.apellido}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${comanda.demoraTotal}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${comanda.precioTotal}"></td>
                                <td>
             <a th:href="@{/comanda/detalle/__${comanda.id}__}" data-toggle="modal" data- 
              target="#exampleModal"><img th:src="@{/img/lupa.png}" width="30"/></a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
          <a th:href="@{/comanda/finalizar/__${comanda.id}__}"><img th:src="@{/img/alta.png}" 
          width="30"/></a>
                                </td>

                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>


        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
        labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Detalle de la comanda</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <table class="table text-capitalize">
                            <thead class="table-dark">
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Precio</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Total</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody th:each="detalle : ${detalle}">
                           <tr>
                            <td th:text="${detalle.menu.nombre}"></td>
                                    <td th:text="${detalle.cantidad}"></td>
                                    <td th:text="${detalle.menu.precio}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${detalle.cantidad * detalle.menu.precio}"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" 
     integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" 
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" 
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
      integrity="sha384-+sLIOodYLS7CIrQpBjl+C7nPvqq+FbNUBDunl/OZv93DB7Ln/533i8e/mZXLi/P+" 
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



   </body>
</html>
```

Mi idea es que al presionar el botòn que tiene th:href="@{/comanda/detalle/**${comanda.id}**}", se envie la informaciòn a la ventana modal. Pero no funciona. no se si el problema esta en el controlador detalleComanda, o en la vista al llamar a ese controlador.
Realice cuna prueba enviando la informacion a una tabla fija al final de la pagina y funciona perfecto, pero en este caso lo que necesito que ese detalle aparezca en la ventana modal emergente.

Alguien me podrìa ayudar ???